# Alinear elementos con imagen de fondo

Tags: html, css, css3

Tengo una imagen de fondo que se ajusta al navegador con `cover` por lo que depende de la resolución la imagen se ajusta al ancho o a la altura.

El tema es que tengo una serie de elementos que quiero que siempre estén sobre un lugar concreto del fondo. Una imagen vale mas que mil palabras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que los tres círculos estén sobre la parte gris en cualquier resolución. No importa que sean más grandes o mas pequeños que la banda gris, solo me interesa que estén posicionados sobre ella.

Pongo el código con un div redimensionable para poder ver el comportamiento:

```css
#contenedor {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("https://preview.ibb.co/nMfMkq/fondo.png") no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: solid 2px #333;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

#circulos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 30%;
}

#circulos>div {
  background-color: #d45500;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="circulos">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Me gustaría encontrar una solución en CSS pero si no es posible me serviría también en javascript.

Comment: ¿Se pueden cambiar los elementos HTML o hay que mantener la estructura dada?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Se puede cambiar todo. Solo necesito mantener el fondo con *cover* y que los círculos sean elementos HTML porque son enlaces en realidad.

Comment: ¿Y se puede usar JavaScript o tiene que ser sólo con HTML + CSS?

Comment: Lo digo en la pregunta, prefiero CSS pero si no es posible podria usar javascript

Comment: La imagen que nos hablas, ¿Es exactamente como la expones? Porque puede reproducirse tal cual en css y poder controlarla mejor. ¿Y tiene que ser con la propiedad cover necesariamente? El problema con cover es que siempre recalcula la imagen dependiendo del alto o el ancho del elemento contenedor en una posición distinta, no es al azar, pero como son tan variantes las posiciones si que cambia siempre la posición de la linea negra.

Comment: @EdgarGutiérrez La imagen que he puesto esta simplificada , la original es muy parecida pero con mas detalles. Si no usará cover podría ajustarlo, ese es el problema, necesito que la imagen ocupe todo el fondo pero no se deforme y otras opciones no me funcionan como quiero.

Comment: No, no encuentro una forma de hacerlo via CSS o Javascript con esas condiciones y menos sin conocer realmente la imagen, ya que habría que interpretar la imagen. Espremos que @AlvaroMontoro pueda llevarte una mejor solución. De momento, solo puedo sugerir que los botones ya este en la imagen y que los botones sean div transparentes ubicados, a la derecha, al medio y a la izquierda ocupando todo el espacio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que debe haber una opción usando sólo CSS... pero no se me ha ocurrido de momento. Una opción que tienes usando JavaScript sería con un [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) para detectar el cambio de tamaño en el `div` contenedor y calcular la posición vertical de los círculos. (También se podría usar `ResizeObserver` pero, al momento de escribir esta respuesta, apenas tiene soporte, por lo que mejor optar por el más genérico `MutationObserver`).

La idea es tan sencilla como se indica arriba: detectar cambios de tamaño, calcular la nueva posición vertical (para lo que hará falta saber el tamaño de la imagen), y aplicársela al contenedor de los círculos. En este caso particular, la imagen de fondo tiene un ancho de 640px, un alto de 534px, y la posición de los círculos está alrededor del 50% (o 267px).

> Nota: Inicialmente tenía un ejemplo más específico (poniendo directamente ancho=640 y alto=534), pero para que se vea mejor de dónde viene cada valor y no usar "números mágicos", lo he cambiado para cargar la imagen y calcular los valores iniciales a partir del tamaño de la imagen... pero si sabes los valores, te puedes ahorrar esa parte si quieres.

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando (los cambios son principalmente JS, manteniendo el HTML igual al inicial, y el CSS apenas tiene cambios mínimos):

```js
// cargamos la imagen de fondo, esto no es necesario realmente, es para hacerlo más genérico y no usar números mágicos (se ve mejor lo que estoy haciendo si indico que es el ancho de la imagen, en lugar de que es 640).
let img = new Image();
img.src = "https://preview.ibb.co/nMfMkq/fondo.png";
img.onload = function() {

  // calculamos su ancho, alto y la posición de la barra horizontal 
  let ancho = img.width;
  let alto = img.height;
  let altoBarra = img.height / 2; // la barra comienza alrededor de la mitad de la imagen
  
  // crea un observador e indica la función a ejecutar
  let observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
    let contenedor = document.querySelector("#contenedor");
    let circulos = document.querySelector("#circulos");
    let ratio = ancho / alto;

    // si ratio es mayor, la parte superior e inferior de la imagen se pierde
    if (contenedor.offsetWidth > contenedor.offsetHeight * ratio) {
      // calcula cuál sería la nueva posición de los círculos
      circulos.style.top = (contenedor.offsetWidth * altoBarra / ancho) + "px";
    // si el ratio es menor, la parte izquierda y derecha de la imagen se pierde
    } else {
      // pero no afecta a los círculos que siguen estando al 50%
      circulos.style.top = "50%";
    }

  });

  // comienza la observación del elemento
  observer.observe(document.querySelector("#contenedor"), {attributes: true});
}
```

```css
#contenedor {
  width: 320px;
  height: 267px;
  background: url("https://preview.ibb.co/nMfMkq/fondo.png") no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: solid 2px #333;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

#circulos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  top: 133px;
}

#circulos>div {
  background-color: #d45500;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="circulos">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ahora que la posición vertical de los círculos es correcta, puedes ampliar el ejemplo para que no sólo se reposicionen, sino que además cambien de tamaño para que siempre tenga la misma proporción.